# Orchard 1.8.1. CMS Meta Description and keyword (Vandelay Module) not working on database upgrade 1.7.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

On a fresh new install 1.8.1 I used the Vandalay,Meta installed and working. A great reason for me to upgrade 1.7.2 database + themes to 1.8.1.

Somehow, I have 1.8.1. running, installed the Module(s), which are enabled, but the extra fields 'SEO keywords' and Met Description are not showing.

Is there a dependency? Can I fix / update in database or config setting? I have full access to dedicated webserver.

Thanks, a very enthausiastic Orchard CMS user. Love the MVC approach from Microsoft.

Comment: There is no incompatibility that I know of. It runs fine on my sites so something else is probably going on. Do you see anything in app_data\logs? Were the extra fields showing before the migration, on the same content items? Did you install the latest version of the module (Vandelay Industries 1.8)?

Comment: Hi Bertrand, the log file doesn't indicate a problem. (old Search index error). 
The extra fields on content form has never showed up. Nor before or after installation.

Comment: Strange, did full new install (WebMatrix 5.0), Orchard 1.8.1, new empty database (SQL2008R2), and installed Vandelay 1.8. Enabled Vandalay Meta.
Bad luck, no SEO / Description fields. 
Can you confirm? Is it 1.8.1 related?

Comment: What content type did you add the part to?

Comment: Solved.
Maybe I was that confused, but adding the part 'Meta' to my content pages solved it. Flabbergasted, but maybe I've overseen it, and thought it was part of automatically install when enabling the Module(s).

Thanks Bertrand!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling the module is not enough: you need to add the part to any content type on which you want to use it.